# Pyinstaller can't find package importlib_metadata

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-importlib

I created a new poetry project.

main.py:

```py
    import importlib_metadata
    
    PACKAGE_NAME = 'try_pyinstaller'
    
    def get_version():
        version = importlib_metadata.version(PACKAGE_NAME)
        return version
    
    def main():
        version = get_version()
        print(version)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

when I run pyinstaller with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name main try_pyinstaller\main.py --clean
```

i get the error:

```
C:\Users\micha\voltfang_software\tests\python\try_pyinstaller\dist>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 381, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_pyinstaller\main.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "try_pyinstaller\main.py", line 10, in main
  File "try_pyinstaller\main.py", line 6, in get_version
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 832, in version
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 805, in distribution
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 383, in from_name
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for try_pyinstaller
[2576] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

The wierd thing is when I just change variable in `version = importlib_metadata.version(PACKAGE_NAME)` to `version = importlib_metadata.version('try_pyinstaller')` it works totally fine. Same environment, nothing else changed. Just put the hardcoded string in.

is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7399

In short:
If you use `importlib_metadata.version('try_pyinstaller')`, PyInstaller's bytecode scanning can infer that metadata for try_pyinstaller needs to be collected. If you use a variant with non-literal argument, `importlib_metadata.version(PACKAGE_NAME)`, it cannot do that, and you need to explicitly instruct it to collect metadata via `--copy-metadata try_pyinstaller`.